# Handling exceptions thrown outside of a try/catch block with Xamarin Insights

Tags: ios, xamarin

It was my understanding that Xamarin.Insights will report all uncought exceptions.

In my tests, when an exception is thrown outside try/catch block, Insights log shows a Crashed event though no exception details are attached. Is it by design or  I am missing something?

Also an attempt to invoke Track or Report inside uncaught exception handler doesn't produce any events/reporting in the log. Even after I restart my app.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) => {

    Insights.Report(e.ExceptionObject);

};
```

I am using Insights 1.7

Answer (score 0):

you need to upload the DSYM files to Xamarin.Insights associated with every iOS app you make available in Release configuration. Only then will your stack traces be symbolicated.

Also, Is still an issue because Insights has been reworked quite often since 11/2014...